# client register code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, master-pages

master1.master

Html

```
 <div id="message" style="direction: rtl; display: none">
  </div>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="padding: 0px;">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="btn" onClick="btn_Click"/>
    </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Code

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "$('#message').text('click click click');";        
    script += "$('#message').dialog({modal:true,resizable:false,title:'پیغام',height:80,show:'clip',hide:'explode'});";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
}
```

this code does not work?????

But But

page1.apx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master1.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="page1.aspx.cs"Inherits="ControlPanelPP" %>
```

Html

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="btn2" onClick="btn2_Click"/>
    </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string script = "$('#message').text('click click click');";        
    script += "$('#message').dialog({modal:true,resizable:false,title:'پیغام',height:80,show:'clip',hide:'explode'});";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
}
```

this code in `page1.aspx`(master.master) work fine!!!

what code in master does not woe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` this js will be written inline with the markup. Wrap you js in `$(document).ready()` method to make sure before you try to find the element it is available in the dom.

```
string script = "$(function(){ $('#message').text('click click click');";        
    script += "$('#message').dialog({modal:true,resizable:false,title:'پیغام',height:80,show:'clip',hide:'explode'}); });";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might have something to do with the fact the the button is placed inside an update panel, and the message div you're trying to updates resides outside of the update panel.

To test whether this is indeed the problem, simply remove the update panel temporarily and see if it works.

Comment: if remove update panel and use ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;cs.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "", script, true);  work fine

Comment: Okay, so the problem is the update panel. Can you put the DIV inside of the update panel somehow?